# why does sd in R return a vector for matrix input, and what can I do about it?

Tags: r

I am somewhat confused as to why the `sd` function in R returns an array for matrix input (I suppose to maintain backwards compatibility, it always will). This is very odd behaviour to me:

```
#3d input, same same
print(length(mean(array(rnorm(60),dim=c(3,4,5)))))
print(length(sd(array(rnorm(60),dim=c(3,4,5)))))
#1d input, same same
print(length(mean(array(rnorm(60),dim=c(60)))))
print(length(sd(array(rnorm(60),dim=c(60)))))
#2d input, different!
print(length(mean(array(rnorm(60),dim=c(12,5)))))
print(length(sd(array(rnorm(60),dim=c(12,5)))))
```

I get

```
[1] 1
[1] 1
[1] 1
[1] 1
[1] 1
[1] 5
```

That is `sd` behaves differently from `mean` when the input is a 2-d array (and apparently only in that case!) Consider then, this failed function to rescale each column of a k-dimensional array by the standard deviation:

```
re.scale <- function(x) {
    #rescale by the standard deviation of each column
    scales <- apply(x,2,sd)
    ret.val <- sweep(x,2,scales,"/")
}

#this works just fine
x <- array(rnorm(60),dim=c(12,5))
y <- re.scale(x)

#this throws a warning
x <- array(rnorm(60),dim=c(3,4,5))
y <- re.scale(x)
```

Is there some other function to replace `sd` without this weird behavior? How would one write `re.scale` properly? Or a Z-score-by-column function?

Comment: Why the down-votes?  This is a perfectly reasonable, well-articulated question.

Comment: Question should probably reflect the changed behaviour in R >= 3.0 (see @Yoshiyuki's answer below).

Answer (score 7):

It is behaving as document in sd's help page. At the very top it announces:

"If x is a matrix or a data frame, a vector of the standard deviation of the columns is returned."

Note it does not say that the arrays are included, so only arrays with two dimensions are included. If you want to stop this behavior, then just make a vector out of it with c():

```
 sd( c(array(rnorm(60),dim=c(12,5))) )
 # [1] 0.9505643
```

I see that you added a request for column z scores. Try this for matrices:

```
colMeans(x)/sd(x)
```

And this for arrays (although the definition of a "column" may need clarification:

```
apply(x, 2:3, mean)/apply(x, 2:3, sd)   # will generalize to higher dimensions
```

Comment: yes, I have read the documentation. my question is _why_ was this choice made? it seems completely arbitrary and does not match, for example, _mean_.

Comment: Although var and sd have the same behavior w.r.t. columns. I do understand why arrays are not given a column treatment. There is, of course, a perfectly good function, colMeans, for getting a vector of column means. I doubt that any of the authors of the S language (which is what R relies upon for it syntactic standard) are likely to be reading this exchange. If my answer does satisfy, you need to ask John Chambers or Trevor Hastie.

Comment: Its because columns of a matrix or data frame are usually the values of the variables of interest. sd(matrix) is then telling you the sds of the variables - and if it went row-wise then you'd be taking the sd of unrelated things. Why then, you say, doesn't mean(matrix) give the column means? Well, mean(data.frame) does, so that's a clue that maybe you should use data frames. But for matrix, I think its just a poor decision made in the early stages of dev of a domain-specific language that not many people were using at the time...

Comment: FWIW,  MatLab does this as well, so clearly "someone" thought it was a good idea.   Just do sd(as.vector(your_matrix)) and all is well.

Comment: actually, Matlab has a consistent API across `mean` and `std`: it applies the operator along a given dimension (defaulting to the first non-trivial dimension). It _never_ pools all the data together. A 'Z-score-by-dimension' operator in Matlab is pretty simple: `@(x,varargin)(bsxfun(@rdivide,bsxfun(@minus,x,mean(x,varargin{:})),std(x,varargin{:}))` How to do this in R is less than clear, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

### The actions of sd were changed:

## 1. version 2.13.2(2011-09-30) and earlier

```
> set.seed(1)
> sd(array(rnorm(60),dim=c(12,5))) 
[1] 0.8107276 1.1234795 0.7925743 0.6186082 0.9464160
```

Description

This function computes the standard deviation of the values in x. If
na.rm is TRUE then missing values are removed before computation
proceeds.
If x is a **matrix or a data frame, a vector of the standard
deviation of the columns** is returned.

---

## 2. R version 2.14.0(2011-10-31) - 2.15.3(2013-03-01)

```
> set.seed(1)
> sd(array(rnorm(60),dim=c(12,5))) 
[1] 0.8107276 1.1234795 0.7925743 0.6186082 0.9464160
 WARNING：
sd(<matrix>) is deprecated.
 Use apply(*, 2, sd) instead.
```

Details

Prior to R 2.14.0, sd(dfrm) worked directly for a data.frame
dfrm. This is now **deprecated** and you are expected to use sapply(dfrm,
sd).

---

## 3. R version 3.0.0 (2013-04-03) and later

```
> sd(array(rnorm(60),dim=c(12,5))) 
[1] 0.8551688
>
(no WARNIG)
```